# What is the best way to show 60+ form fields details on a dashboard screen?

Tags: forms, dashboard

I have a use case where I have a dashboard, and my requirement is to display 60+ form fields on the dashboard screen. I am thinking of grouping them, although that might make it too overwhelming for the user. What are some alternatives to this?

The domain is hotel management, where the dashboard screen is for executives to know about a member's information. There are contract information fields and contact information fields which I have to display on one screen for ease of access.
For example:

- Contract ID: 2345677
- Product Owned: Yes
- Sale Posted Date: 20/05/2020
- VIP Flag: Yes
- HWC Flag: Yes
- HWC Reason: Comments
- Last Holidayed Resort:
- Last Holidayed Date:
- Travel Agent Flag:
- Servicing Location:
- Pending Cancellation:
- RCP Balance:
- HFRP Balance:

Apart from this, there are separate fields for contact information which I have to display on a single screen. These are only to display information and do not accept user input. For example:

- email
- residence address
- Guest fees
- VIP Reason
- VIP Flag

Comment: Sensible grouping is your best option. Perhaps also consider some sort of "quick find" feature too - a simple textbox that lets the user enter a term and highlights/filters the fields that match.

Comment: @musefan If you'd considering adding this as an answer, this would enable the community to vote on this suggestion.

Comment: First of all, why are there form fields on a dashboard? Can you give more details around the domain, use case, and why someone thinks that a 60 field form should be there? let's also see some of your efforts so far...that will prompt some potential answers. This forum works best with detailed context and you bringing some of your attempts...

Comment: @musefan your  idea can work but I want to display form fields details for example Name: musefan something like how this will work in quick find feature can you please elaborate ? This can be helpful

Comment: @divyadave: Well it really depends on what your fields are doing. Can you provide some real examples in your question, perhaps 5-10 would suffice? Also, I originally assumed this was like a configuration sort of page where the user might know what fields can be searched, but if this is a user data collection type page they are unlikely to know the fields by name. Do you expect the user to complete all fields in one go, or can they perhaps change just 1 at any given time?

Comment: @maxathousand I had thought about it, but I am conscious that there isn't enough information yet to give a good/accurate answer. Let's see if the OP can provide us some more details

Comment: @musefan I have edited my question hope this helps.

Comment: Based on the amount of information you have to present, you can group them in different levels: menus, submenus, content groups, etc. Based on the information you gave, i would recommend dividing all info per submenu first, and then visually group the rest per page. Make sure the information is divided/grouped logically and intuitively, so the user doesn't have to spend much time or effort finding what they're looking for.

Comment: @SirExotic do you have any example ?

Comment: @divyadave I think the profile page on this website is a great example. It divides information into subjects and each subject has its own submenu.

Answer (score 3):

Interview the executives/stakeholders to understand:

- When and how are they using this information?
- What do they need to know quickly?
- What is less important but still might need to be accessed?

Once you have that information, categorize and cluster the important fields to make them easily accessible (you could use a card sorting exercise for this), and consider an "Advanced" or "More" button that can be clicked on to reveal the items that are seldom needed.

Test this out with the stakeholders and see how quickly they're able to find what they need.

Answer (score 2):

*As a preface, I'm going to draw very heavily here on some ideas presented by Adam Wathan & Steve Schroger in their [Refactoring UI](https://refactoringui.com/) approach, and would suggest referencing it if you can.*

You might consider changing your approach of how you are showing the data.  Specifically, in your question you are showing a database-like view with a *label: value* format.  This is probably how the data is stored, but it doesn't allow you a way to show any sort of hierarchy; all data is given equal emphasis.

Keep in mind that the *value* is what is important, not the label.  And there are different ways to help someone understand the context of the value, not just by giving it a label.

Take for example this contact display from Microsoft Office.  Note that there are very few labels, but the values and their meanings are easy to see and easy to understand.

[image: Sample Microsoft Office Contact]

Here are some more specific examples of how to get away from using *label: value* ...

1. If you are listing someone's phone number, you don't need to label the field - it's obvious it's a phone number.  If they have multiple numbers, then sure - put a label on to differentiate them.
2. If you are listing the price of an item, you don't need to label the price, just show it, perhaps with a larger font to make it stand out.
3. If you are listing contact information for a person, you can simply give their name without a label.  If they have a job title, you don't need to label the title, just show it under their name.  E.g. "Tim Holt / Software Developer" defines me without having to apply labels.
4. Sometimes the label just becomes clarifying text, not a label.  Instead of "Days remaining: 5" I can say "5 days remaining".

Answer (score 1):

Group the cards or charts in a proper manner with callout for each card which can hightlight the top finding. A search on the page is MUST which will show the related cards.

We had a similar requirement for one of the product but we have 120 different metric to show... we categories all the 120 cards into logical group and added a NLP driven search which find the right card and also filters the content in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

If the content of that section is simply to show all 60 forms, I don't see any inconvenience in listing them all on the page.

This is an example of an online radio [DI.FM](https://www.di.fm/channels) with 96 different channels including name, current song, author, picture and a play button. The biggest job will be creating each form thumbnail.

Comment: It's not 60 forms, its 60 form fields

Comment: I see. My answer is the same anyway, I don't see any problem in putting 60 form fields on a page. Any graphic example about your problem can help to get a helpful answer.